# How should I fill with color the nav-bar? - css

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I want to make a website menu and I made the following code with HTML and CSS. The problem is that there is a whitespace between the home and the Home and the Contact. Any ideas to solve this problem?

```css
li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 3vh;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #595959;
}

#about, #gallery, #contact {
    float: right;
}

#home {
    float: left;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #969696;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NavBar Tutorial</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the items in a wrapper?

Comment: Do you want it to be aligned to the left like this: https://imgur.com/a/e4ayr6b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might actually be looking for something like this. I've changed your items to classes vs IDs because this is better practice.

I'd also not set the padding on the `a` element because you may need to use this elsewhere. Below is a starting point to show you the desired effect but you should start over with the same code but modify your CSS classes so that you have specific classes for your header vs affecting that property for the whole site straight away as it will cause issues later on.

```css
li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 3vh;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #595959;
}

.right-item {
    float: right;
}

.left-item {
    float: left;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #969696;
}

.nav-wrap {
    background-color: #595959;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NavBar Tutorial</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrap">
            <li><a href="#" class="left-item">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="right-item">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="right-item">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="right-item">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty straightforward.

In your CSS, you have said that the about, gallery, and contact have a float right.
So that will bring these 3 element to the right while you said that the home element has to be floated to the left.

So it will align it to the left thus creating the white space in between them. If you want to remove the white space and align all these 4 elements together like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipdKx.jpg
Then the code is simple:

```
#about,
#gallery,
#contact {
  float: left;
}
```

Now this float left will align the other 3 elements with the home button.

And then the home will still have the `float: left`.

If you don't want that, then your question doesn't say that should the elements be aligned to the left or what. You just said the white space should be removed. So the above solution will do it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 3vh;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #595959;
}


a:hover {
    background-color: #969696;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NavBar Tutorial</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

You are applying float property to your menu items, which is not neeeded.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 3vh;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #595959;
}
a:hover {
background-color: #969696;
}
  nav{
text-align:right;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NavBar Tutorial</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Though this is not ideal for a real-world website. I hope it will help